# How to let QR reading based on database

Tags: reactjs, qr-code

I have program that can read QR image but not giving me if it is authorised or not based on array of objects in JSON database.

react code

```
const handleScan = (result, error) => {

const findCode = codes.find(code => {
    return code.email === result?.text;
});
console.log(findCode);
setAuthentication("Auth");
if (error) {
    console.info(error);
}
}

return (
<div className="container">
<QrReader
delay={300}

onResult={handleScan}

style={{ height: 240, width: 320 }}

facingMode="environment"

value={mailto:${email}} />

The Scan result is: {authentication}

</div>
</div>
);
```